# How can I record a physics animation in the BGE

Tags: rendering, animation, game-engine, physics

I made a bullet physics simulation in blender game where a bullet moves by use of key framing and collides with cell fractured objects.

The objects are two rectangles and I used game logic bricks to stop the simulation of the objects until the bullet reaches them. The simulation works fine when I press <kbd>P</kbd>, and it appears to be recording correctly, but when I try to press the play button underneath the timeline after I end the game it doesn't play what I just recorded.

It usually plays back the simulation as if the logic bricks were not being used (the cell fractured objects fall before the bullet reaches them). My goal is recording the animation and rendering it using Cycles.

My simulation is very similar to the [Blender Cookie fracturing a cup of coffee tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zkrvrQDDcPQ).

Comment: Hi, are you sure you can't achieve the same result using normal rigid body physics in Blender? There are a few tricks you can use to stop the objects from simulating until it get's hit by your projectile. Also, it might be a good idea for you to upload a .blend file.

Comment: Note that blender has had a rigid body sim built into the 3D view since that tutorial was made

Comment: [Record Animation In BGE](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/8876/2217) is the same problem you are having. While you can not do it in the game engine, you can use the built in rigid body physics, and bypass the bge all together.

Comment: thanks for the idea! Not totally sure how to do that but it makes sense so I'll try to figure that out, thanks!